# Change the height of a static UITableViewCell only possible by overriding heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've looked through lots of examples of how to hide a static `UITableViewCell` by overridding `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, and while I've now got it working it just seems so cumbersome that I'd like to see if I'm doing something wrong.

I have a `UITableViewController` with a table view that has about 8 rows. This screen in my app shows a single object, so for example one row is description, one is an image, one holds a map view, etc. All of the rows are static.

In some cases, some of the objects that are shown don't have a map, so I want to hide the row that holds the `mapview`. Since it's a static row, I was thinking that by having an outlet property for that row (e.g. `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *mapViewRow;`), then I could somehow set that row's height to 0 or hide that row in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`. However, it seems like the only way to do this is to override the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, which is kind of annoying because then I need to hardcode the index of the map row in my code, e.g.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 6 && self.displayItem.shouldHideMap) {
        return 0;
    }
    return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Of course, not a big deal, but just the whole way of sizing *static* rows in a `tableview` seems like it defeats the point of setting them up in the storyboard in the first place.

Comment: You have static tableView with static rows, so hardcoded indexes should be ok. I'm using enum, which hides absolute numbers.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** - rationale behind my answer

To change the height of a row you must reload either the whole table or a subset containing that row. B/c it's a bit odd to have a row in the table w/ zero height, I prefer modifying your  data source such that the row doesn't exist in the table.

There are a number of ways to do that. You could build an array from your displayItem where each row in the array corresponds to a row in the table w/ appropriate data. You would rebuild this array and then call `[tableView reloadData]`. My original answer would also eliminate the unwanted row by treating each data element as a section with 0 or 1 rows.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Is your tableview a plain or grouped style? If it's a plain style, you could treat each row as a section with either 0 or 1 rows in it. In your tableView dataSource and delegate methods you would use the section index to identify the data within `self.displayItem` that you care about for that section.

Your code would be something like:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 8; // max number of possible rows in table
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger rows = 1;

    // set self.mapSectionIndex during initialization or hard code it
    if (section == self.mapSectionIndex && self.displayItem.shouldHideMap) {
        rows = 0;
    }
    return rows;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
{
    return 60.0f; // whatever you want the height to be
}

// also modify tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and any other tableView delegate and dataSource methods appropriately
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override  `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and just write in it `return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;` this will make cell calculate the height automatically as `UILabel` height is >= . it worked for me.